# python logger - log extra arguments

Tags: python, python-logging

I have got a logger set up in databricks that saves the output as json files in blob storage.  This works fine but I would like to add the data I pass into "extra" into the output JSON as top level keys.

This was the suggestion by the databricks AI assistant but extra_fields doesn't seem to ever return anything.  Can you suggest what I'm doing wrong?

```
import json
import logging
import uuid
from datetime import datetime
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient


class AzureDataLakeLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, account_name, credential, file_system_name, directory_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.account_name = account_name
        self.credential = credential
        self.file_system_name = file_system_name
        self.directory_name = directory_name
        self.file_name = str(uuid.uuid4().hex) + ".txt"
        self.client = DataLakeServiceClient(
            account_url=f"https://{account_name}.dfs.core.windows.net",
            credential=credential,
        )
        self.file_system_client = self.client.get_file_system_client(
            file_system=file_system_name
        )

    def emit(self, record):
        # Convert timestamp to ISO format
        iso_timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(record.created).isoformat()
        log_entry = record
        extra_fields = log_entry.__dict__.get("extra", None)
        extra_fields_str = str(extra_fields) if extra_fields else ""

        # Add each field in extra_fields to the log_data dictionary
        log_data = {
            "timestamp": iso_timestamp,
            "message": log_entry.msg,
        }
        print(extra_fields)
        if extra_fields is not None:
            for key, value in extra_fields.items():
                if isinstance(value, str):
                    log_data[key] = value
                else:
                    log_data[f'{key}_json'] = json.dumps(value)

        log_json = json.dumps(log_data, default=str)
        self.upload_to_azure_datalake(log_json)
        
    def upload_to_azure_datalake(self, log_json):
        file_path = f"{self.directory_name}/{self.file_name}"
        file_client = self.file_system_client.get_file_client(file_path)

        if not file_client.exists():
            file_client.create_file()

        file_client.upload_data(log_json, overwrite=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace the following values with your Azure Data Lake Storage details
    account_name, credential, file_system_name, directory_name = (
        "testbrh",
        "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==",
        "logs",
        "logs",
    )

    # Create the log handler
    log_handler = AzureDataLakeLogHandler(
        account_name, credential, file_system_name, directory_name
    )

    # Create a logger and add the custom log handler
    logger = logging.getLogger("azure_datalake_logger")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.handlers.clear()
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
  

    logger.debug("This is a debug message.",extra={"Test":"testvalue"})
```